# How can I define and use an active pattern with a non-inferrable type argument?

Tags: f#

I tried the following:

```
let inline (|OpAdd|_|) (aty:Type, x:obj, y:obj) =
    if aty.Equals(typeof<'a>) then Some(box ((unbox<'a> x) + (unbox<'a> y)))
    else None

//FSI given signature: 
//val inline ( |OpAdd|_| ) : Type * obj * obj -> obj option
```

Which gives no warnings or errors, but I can't figure out how to pass the explicit type argument at the call site and it seems that `'a` is always inferred as `int`.

When I try to place the explicit parameter in the definition, I get a couple warnings and errors:

```
let inline (|OpAdd|_|)<'a> (aty:Type, x:obj, y:obj) =
    if aty.Equals(typeof<'a>) then Some(box ((unbox<'a> x) + (unbox<'a> y)))
    else None

warning FS1189: Type parameters must be placed directly adjacent to the type name, e.g.       "type C<'T>", not     type "C   <'T>"

error FS0001: The declared type parameter 'a' cannot be used here since the type parameter cannot be resolved at compile time
```

Is it possible for active patterns to have explicit type parameters? If so how do I define and use them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure whether there is a clean way to do this (probably not, but I may be wrong).

As a dirty workaround, you can add a dummy parameter of type `'T` (when working with primitive types that have easy-to-create values) or of type `Expr<'T>` (when you don't really want to create an instance). Then you can use the pattern with some dummy parameter that specifies the type:

```
let inline (|OpAdd|_|) (e:Expr<'T>) (aty:Type, x:obj, y:obj) =
    if aty.Equals(typeof<'T>) then Some(box ((unbox<'T> x) + (unbox<'T> y)))
    else None

let dummy<'T> : 'T = failwith "!"

match (typeof<float>, box 1.1, box 2.1) with 
| OpAdd <@ dummy<int> @> res -> res
| OpAdd <@ dummy<float> @> res -> res
| _ -> null
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's any way to do what you want because I don't think it really makes sense.  How would the compiler infer the type argument when the active pattern is used?

That is, given

```
function
| OpAdd x -> ...
```

how would the compiler know what `'a` should be?

As I see it, you have two options.  One is to reflect `'a` in the return type of your pattern:

```
let inline (|OpAdd|_|) (aty:System.Type, x:obj, y:obj) =
    if aty.Equals(typeof<'a>) then Some((unbox<'a> x + unbox<'a> y) : 'a)
    else None

let (OpAdd(x:int)) = typeof<int>, box 1, box 2
let (OpAdd(y:float)) = typeof<float>, box 3.0, box 4.0
```

The other is to reflect `'a` in one of the inputs to your pattern (perhaps along the lines of Tomas's answer).

Comment: I suppose you might want to write `function | OpAdd<int> x -> ...`, but that's not (currently) syntactically valid.

Comment: @kvb - while I'm actually using your approach of making the return type generic (and boxing later), I gave @Tomas the check-mark because his solution is more general when you have no such luxury.